# how to add 3 months to timer on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to change and add 3 months to `var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 29, 2020 14:55:10").getTime();` on click of  success button.

````
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
    <ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><h5 id="days"></h5></a>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><h5 id="hours"></h5></a>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><h5 id="mins"></h5></a>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><h5 id="secs"></h5></a>
  
</ul>
    <br>
    <p class="card-text">
    <button type="button" id="success" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
         
    <script>
    // The data/time we want to countdown to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 29, 2020 14:55:10").getTime();

    // Run myfunc every second
    var myfunc = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var timeleft = countDownDate - now;
        
    // Calculating the days, hours, minutes and seconds left
    var days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
    // Result is output to the specific element
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days + "d "
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours + "h " 
    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = minutes + "m " 
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = seconds + "s " 
     
     setInterval(function()  {
  if(timeleft > "0") document.getElementById("success").style.display="none";
     
});


        
 // Display the message when countdown is over
    if (timeleft < "0") {
        clearInterval(myfunc);
        document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = "0" + "d "
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "0" + "h "
        document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = "0" + "m "
        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = "0" + "s "
        document.getElementById("success").style.display = "inline";
        
    }
    }, 1000);
    </script>```
````

Comment: The `Date` API provides a `setMonth` method. When the button is clicked, set the value to the current month plus one.

Comment: what do you mean by adding 3 months? because the months don't have the same number of days, just adding 3 to the month's valuation can easily give a wrong date...

Comment: @MisterJojo I see the flaw in my wording, i think saying 90 days is more of what i mean. as the timer is for some equipment to be checked where as a couple days wont make a difference.

Comment: To add 90 days use: `dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate()+90)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it that you are looking for ?

```js
const dateItems  = document.querySelectorAll('#count-down span')
  ,   one_Sec    = 1000
  ,   one_Min    = one_Sec * 60
  ,   one_Hour   = one_Min * 60 
  ,   one_Day    = one_Hour * 24
  ,   bt90days   = document.getElementById('bt-90days')
  ,   targetDate = document.getElementById('target-date')
  ,   dateOption =
        { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
        , hour12:true, hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'
        }
  ,   intl_Date  = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, dateOption )
  ;
var dateTarget    = new Date('Nov 3, 2020 14:55:10')
  , countDownDate = dateTarget.getTime()
  ;
targetDate.textContent = intl_Date.format(dateTarget)
  ;
var timerIntv = setInterval(()=>
  {
  let now      = new Date().getTime()
    , timeleft = countDownDate - now
    , timVals  = [0,0,0,0]
    ;
  if (timeleft > 0)
    {
    timVals[0] = Math.floor( timeleft / one_Day)              // days
    timVals[1] = Math.floor((timeleft % one_Day)  / one_Hour) // hours
    timVals[2] = Math.floor((timeleft % one_Hour) / one_Min ) // minutes
    timVals[3] = Math.floor((timeleft % one_Min)  / one_Sec ) // seconds
    }
  else
    {
    clearInterval(timerIntv)
    }
  dateItems.forEach((el,i)=>el.textContent = timVals[i])
  }
  , 1000) // setInterval 1s
  ;
bt90days.onclick=_=>
  {
  dateTarget.setDate(dateTarget.getDate() + 90) 
  targetDate.textContent = intl_Date.format(dateTarget)
  countDownDate = dateTarget.getTime()
  // countDownDate += 90 *one_Day  // add 90 days to countDown
  }
```

```css
#count-down span::after {font-size: .8em; }
#count-down span:nth-of-type(1)::after { content: 'd '; }
#count-down span:nth-of-type(2)::after { content: 'h '; }
#count-down span:nth-of-type(3)::after { content: 'm '; }
#count-down span:nth-of-type(4)::after { content: 's '; }
```

```html
<p id=target-date></p>
<p id="count-down">
  countdown : <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
</p>
<button id="bt-90days" > add 90 days </button>
```

Comment: one thing is that it doesn't store the date it resets after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should increase the date by 90 days.

```
countDownDate += 86400 * 90
```